# In Flutter, how to show results immediately after `showSearch()` is called with a query parameter?

Tags: flutter

Currently I am hacking my way out like this:
In the `buildSuggestions(BuildContext context)` method, at the top, I entered these lines:

```
if (builtSuggestionsForTheFirstTime == false) {
  if (query.length > 0) {
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 50)).then((_) {
      showResults(context);
    });
  }
  builtSuggestionsForTheFirstTime = true;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @pskink I am sorry, but can you please elaborate on how `debounce()` method can help?

Comment: "i assume you use Future.delayed since you dont want suggestions on each key typed"; Sorry, but this is not what I want. What I want to achieve is, when the search screen is opened using `showSearch()` global function along with a query parameter, I want to show the search results immediately. Currently, to show the results / build the results, user have to press enter button on the soft keyboard (without the above code)

Comment: @pskink Thank you for detailed code. " here the list appears right after calling..." Isn't this the Suggestions list? What I want to show right after calling `showSearch(...)` is Results list.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is, that `_currentBody` and its setter inside `search.dart` are private.

I found a slightly better approach by calling `showResults` after calling `showSearch`:

```
MyDelegate myDelegate = MyDelegate();
showSearch(context: context, delegate: myDelegate, query: 'My query');
myDelegate.showResults(context);
```

If you want to fork `search.dart`, you can also change the following line:

```
//delegate._currentBody = SearchBody.suggestions;
delegate._currentBody = query.isNotEmpty ? SearchBody.results : SearchBody.suggestions;
```